# Change Date Format in Django Models when retrieving Data from PostgreSQL showing in form

Tags: python, django, postgresql, bootstrap-4

I'm using django to submit data in postgresql database. Submission work fine and datastapm on database is correct and match with timezone.
I'm useing bellow code to crate time and use in database.
`created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`

format of time in database:

`2021-10-05 20:18:41.773503+03:30`

Issue is here that when getting data from database and show it on table, time zone not correct and data format changing to `Oct. 5, 2021, 4:48 p.m.` without timezone

How can I make this correct on view form and show it like `2021-10-05 20:18:41`

[image]

Comment: See [L10N](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_L10N).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks, timezone is correct now, do you have any idea about the format?

Comment: You didn't say what you did, so there is no way to come up with an answer.

Comment: I changed `TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tehran'`  and `USE_L10N = True`, i tried to change format in setting.py  to `TIME_FORMAT='P'
DATE_FORMAT='m/d/Y'

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS=['%Y-%m-%d']
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%H:%M:%S']` format not changed!

Comment: From docs [Settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-TIME_FORMAT) "Note that if USE_L10N is set to True, then the locale-dictated format has higher precedence and will be applied instead.". So I'm guessing your locale uses the output format you are seeing. In other words try with `USE_L10N = False`.